# Jquery How To Stop Append from Appending Previous Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble to display the star of each hotel and not sure on how to do it. I have like 5 hotels, and each has different value of hotelStar.

My Javascript code:

```
function GetStarHotel() {
    var parent    = $(' p.star '),
        imagePath = 'image/hotelstar.png',
        img;
for (var i = 0; i < hotelStar; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = imagePath;    
        $(parent).append('<img src="image/hotelstar.png" class="hotelStar" />')
    }

}
```

And my HTML Code is:

```
<h1>Hotel 1</h1>
<p class="star"><script>
        hotelStar = 4;
        GetStarHotel();
        </script></p>
<h1>Hotel 2</h1>
<p class="star"><script>
        hotelStar = 3;
        GetStarHotel();
        </script></p>
<h1>Hotel 3</h1>
<p class="star"><script>
        hotelStar = 2;
        GetStarHotel();
        </script></p>
```

It is adding my previous Hotel's Stars. How can I prevent it from adding the same element?

Comment: you are adding the same image everytime??

Comment: Yes, the star is in image file and it's a small image, I could do it with IF Else statement inside the hotel detail. I'm just trying to list hotel names with the stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `append()` you can use `.html()`, check updated code below

```
function GetStarHotel() {
    var parent    = $(' p.star '),
        imagePath = 'image/hotelstar.png',
        img,
        star = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hotelStar; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = imagePath;    
            star += '<img src="'+imagePath +'" class="hotelStar" />';
        }
    $(parent).html(star)

}
```

> i have simplified your code. check updated snippet below

```js
$('p.star').each(function(){
    count = $(this).data('star'),
    star = '',
    imagePath = 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/download-png-image-star-png-image-1.png';
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        star += '<img src="'+imagePath +'" width="16" class="hotelStar" alt="'+i+'" />';
    }
    $(this).html(star)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hotel 1</h1>
<p class="star" data-star ="4" ></p>
<h1>Hotel 2</h1>
<p class="star" data-star ="3"></p>
<h1>Hotel 3</h1>
<p class="star" data-star ="2"></p>
```

Comment: Now the latest hotelStar overwrites all <p class="star"></p>

Eg.
Hotel 1
hotelStar = 5

Hotel 2
hotelStar = 2

Hotel 3
hotelStar = 4

Now everything shows 4 stars instead